# JQuery Autocomplete Problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I know that there are already a bunch of problems associated with the JQuery autocomplete UI widget, but none of those worked. I'm simply writing code based on the presented source here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
This is my JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).ready(function(){
    $('#txtcity').keypress(function(){
        $("#txtschool").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#txtschool").val('');
    });

    $('#txtcity').focusout(function(){
        if($('#txtcity').val()!=""){
            var availableSchools = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "do_findschools.php?city="+$('#txtcity').val()
            }).done(function(data){
                availableSchools = data.split(',');
                alert(data);
            });

            $('#txtschool').autocomplete({
                source: availableSchools,
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

as simple as it is, when I type in stuff in txtschool, nothing pops up. I also used the Chrome built in debugger but it shows no errors. The UI simply doesn't work. The ajax **works fine** since I see the right data at the alert() line. I've also imported:

```
<link href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my header file.
Why is it not working?

Comment: may be, `$(document).ready()` ? autocomplete itself [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hfNdg/)

Comment: also better to use json in request, btw *why you guys use complex `ajax` method when here is shorthands for `post` and `get` ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code initializing the widget is being executed *before* your AJAX request comes back. If you place your `alert` where you're initializing autocomplete, `availableSchools` will be empty.

Place your autocomplete initialization code inside of the `done` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "do_findschools.php?city="+$('#txtcity').val()
}).done(function(data){
    availableSchools = data.split(',');
    $('#txtschool').autocomplete({
        source: availableSchools,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Also, I think you want `$(document).ready()` and not `$(document.body).ready()`

Comment: I see... It looks so simple now. Tested it and worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request is async. So when you set the source the ajax request hasn't returned yet and availableSchools =[]. You can either call the ajax request with async:false. This is not recommended. Or you can move the autocomplete into the done function.

```
     $('#txtcity').focusout(function(){
        if($('#txtcity').val()!=""){
            var availableSchools = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: "do_findschools.php?city="+$('#txtcity').val()
            }).done(function(data){
                availableSchools = data.split(',');
```

$('#txtschool').autocomplete({
            source: availableSchools,
            dataType: "json"
            alert(data);
        });

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 1.9.0, the drop down list of entries for autocomplete was hidden by other UI components.
However, the control functionality works.
In developer tools (F12) you can see that rendering the component takes unexpected more time. In this time, the class of the autocomplete field change from

```
medium required ui-autocomplete-input
```

to

```
medium required ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading
```

and then back.

The list starts from right below the right field but is not on on top.
Simmilar issue occurred with accordion after migration from 1.8.3.

[image]